ANSYS MAXWELL busbar analysis
I'm trying to simulate busbar using ansys maxwell and solution type is electric transient  (dc current, transient).
There's one current source and several sinks which have defined sink current-time profiles. But I can't designate current profile to sinks.
I'm trying to convert sink and source to set current profiles. Would it be affect to busbar current density or thermal dissipation?

In another FEM application I am familiar with, I would use the electric currents module. The input would be grounded and time-dependent currents would be specified at the various outputs. The application would solve for the time-dependent current distribution.
I suggest you look at examples provided for Maxwell, usually this is the best way to get started.
